# Pandas DF dtype ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i am trying to convert all columns of a dataframe read of a csv to float. When i execute the following code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('statistic.csv', 
parse_dates=True, index_col=['DATE'], dtype={'QUANTITY' : 'float', 
low_memory=False)
```

Here is how the data.head() looks like without the dtype argument:

```
                        ACCEPTOR    QUANTITY      ARTICLENO
DATE                                                                           
2014-07-07 00:00:00.0           1      348  434070668          
2014-08-11 00:00:00.0           1      281  434070668
2014-08-18 00:00:00.0           1      835  434070668
2014-08-25 00:00:00.0           1      147  434070668
2014-09-08 00:00:00.0           1      569  434070668
```

With the dtype option i get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'QUANTITY'
```

Background: I need to convert this to float manually, because pandas does not recognize the data type (csv has about 1 billion rows/ 400 MB) automatically for those large files (for about 500000 rows it does automatically).
Later on it can happen, that there are multiple quantity entries for the same article number at the same date, so i need a numeric type to prevent string concatenation because i execute the following code to prepare my dataframe for some machine learning:

```
data_extracted = data.groupby(['DATE','ARTICLENO']) 
['QUANTITY'].sum().unstack()
```

I know that QUANTITY is not a valid float, but how do i tell pandas not to convert the column headers?

EDIT: Here is a copy-paste of how the csv looks like:

```
ACCEPTOR    QUANTITY    ARTICLENO   DATE
1            348    434070668       2014-07-07 00:00:00.0
1            281    434070668       2014-08-11 00:00:00.0
1            835    434070668       2014-08-18 00:00:00.0
1            147    434070668       2014-08-25 00:00:00.0
1            569    434070668       2014-09-08 00:00:00.0
1            890    434070668       2014-09-22 00:00:00.0
1            358    434070668       2014-09-29 00:00:00.0
1            359    434070668       2014-10-06 00:00:00.0
1            166    434070668       2014-10-27 00:00:00.0
1            235    434070668       2014-11-24 00:00:00.0
1            378    434070668       2014-12-15 00:00:00.0
```

Comment: Can you share how your input CSV file looks (as opposed to the dataframe result)? By default, columns should feed *as columns*, not *as data*.

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**Option 1**

```
data = pd.read_csv('statistic.csv', 
parse_dates=True, index_col=['DATE'], dtype={'QUANTITY' : 'float', 
low_memory=False, dtype={'QUANTITY': np.float64})
```

**Option 2**

```
data[['QUANTITY']] = data[['QUANTITY']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: i tried option 2 already before, producing the same result. I will try option 1 though

Comment: option 2 worked, only problem: my article numbers are converted to float too, which is slightly bad because i use them in the further steps as column headers. any way to avoid or revert this in later steps?